# I would like to Automatically sort a Google Sheet highest to lowest, then remove duplicate values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that contains an inventory list that include manufacturer and model id's. Each line item contains a price and the amount the product is discounted below MSRP. I have the raw information dumping into a spreadsheet daily but I need the sheet to automatically sort the sheet by the make/model/highest discount value and then remove the duplicates (Removing all of the lower make/model/discount values). I could easily do this task manually but I am hoping to find a scaleable way to perform this tasks for many different lists.

Answer (score 0):

**To get UNIQUE Id's** paste this formula in `F2`.

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

In `G2` Paste this formula and drag down.

```
=IF(F2="",,SORTN(FILTER($B$2:$D,$A$2:$A=F2),1,,4,0,3,0))
```

Note: duplicates are highlighted in yellow and green

[image]

Comment: Thank you, let's say model id ID_IJWZ has multiple values for "amount". I want the highest one and the others can be ignored. Will this still work?

Comment: Sorry tried to upload a screen shot example but let's say the values are:
ID_IJWZ 36 12 50.00%
ID_IJWZ 37 11 42.31%
ID_IJWZ 38 9 31.03%
ID_IJWZ 36 10 38.46%
ID_IJWZ 35 12 52.17%

Comment: It would return ID_IJWZ $35.00 12 52.17% the answer is updated

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will attempt to set up a test run now..Thanks you!